# Struts logic:iterate does not recognize the collection

Tags: struts-1

I am trying to display the collection that I am setting in struts action to
the request scope.
 But when I try to use struts `<logic:iterate>` to display the collection,
 it says can not find str2 bean in any scope.

### In Action class:

```
Set<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(datetimestamp));
Collection str2 = new Vector();

System.out.println("UNique Array :   "+uniqueWords);

String[] str1 = uniqueWords.toArray(new String[0]);
for(int p=0;p<str1.length;p++)
{
    str2.add(str1[i]);
}
request.setAttribute("str2", str2);
```

I don't have getter setter method for this I just want to iterate this collection in JSP

But In JSP, it does not recognize

### the collection:

```
<logic:iterate name="str2" id="str2Id" indexId="idx" scope="request">
    <p>
        <script>
            l[m]='<bean:write name="str2Id"/>';
            m++;
        </script>
    </p>
</logic:iterate>
```

### Mapping

```
<action path="/online" name="onlineMonitoringGraphForm" 
        scope="request" validate="true">
    <forward name="success" path="/WEB-INF/jsp/Success.jsp" /> 
    <forward name="failed" path="/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp" /> 
</action>
```

I am clueless about why the bean is invisible in any scope?

Comment: Are you sure that there is no browser redirection between the Action and the JSP? Can you provide the mapping associated with this action and the forwards you are doing in it?

Comment: this the my mapping                                                         <action path="/online" name="onlineMonitoringGraphForm" scope="request" validate="true">
<forward name="success" path="/WEB-INF/jsp/Success.jsp" />
<forward name="failed" path="/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp" />
</action>

Comment: I have done browser redirection ..

Comment: Check properly , it's only mapping issue.

Comment: There is no mapping issue I checked it properly ....                  If you want should I share whole code ??